# Hibernate does not save Object when using @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am learning `Hibernate` with `MySql` data base, while making small project i come up with strange behave of hibernate. I am trying to save one entity (code is below), but entity not getting persist into DB. i am using `session.save(e)` method only. It is working if i am using `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` and not if i am using `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`.

Again if i use session transaction (`begin and commit`) it is working in both case (AUTO and IDENTITY).

Again if i use two different entity one with AUTO and another with IDENTITY it is working.

First Entity

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "EMP_ID")
    private int empId;

    @Column(name ="name")
    private String name;

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Second Entity

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "SUPEMPLOYEE")
public class SupperEmploye {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "EMP_ID")
    private int empId;

    @Column(name ="name")
    private String name;

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Code for save entity

```
Session s= HibernateConfig.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        //s.getTransaction().begin(); //working if add

        Employee e= new Employee();
        e.setName("Employee");
        s.save(e);

        SupperEmploye se = new SupperEmploye();
        se.setName("Super Employee");
        s.save(se);

        s.close();
        //s.getTransaction().commit(); // Working if add
        HibernateConfig.getSessionFactory().close();
```

> NOTE: Using hibernate 5, MySQL 8, JAVA 8

please comment if need more info

Comment: Try with @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")

Comment: @Sambit getting Error, No generator named "native" is defined in the persistence unit, do need some config?

Comment: No configuration is required.

Comment: You can also try Identity generator to check whether you are able to save or not.

Comment: it working after adding @GenericGenerator(name = "native",strategy = "native"), Thanks

Comment: in other case it is working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
```

instead of

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Read below this nice article on this.

https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is working with generates, i was wonder for AUTO only

Comment: Answers that consist only of code are still answers.